# How To Get New Persona Behavior in PeoplePicker

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

The documentation allows you to enter any string, hit [Tab] and it will display it as a persona. Trying to replicate this behavior, but am having trouble and the sample code says nothing.

[image: The behavior I want]

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/peoplepicker

My PeoplePicker:

```
<CompactPeoplePicker
    getTextFromItem={(item) => { return item.text; } }
    onItemSelected={(item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(item);
        })
    }}
    selectedItems={this.state.currentSelectedItems}
    onChange={(items) => { 
        console.log(items);
        this.setState({ currentSelectedItems: items}); 
    }}
    onResolveSuggestions={this._onResolveSuggestions}
    className={'ms-PeoplePicker'} 
    pickerSuggestionsProps={{
        suggestionsHeaderText: 'Suggested People',
        mostRecentlyUsedHeaderText: 'Suggested Contacts',
        noResultsFoundText: 'No results found',
        loadingText: 'Loading',
        showRemoveButtons: true,
        suggestionsAvailableAlertText: 'People Picker Suggestions available',
        suggestionsContainerAriaLabel: 'Suggested contacts'
    }}
/>
```

[image: The behavior I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to simply return a new `Persona` as part of `onResolveSuggestions`

```
_onResolveSuggestions = (filterText, ...) => {
    var suggestions = ...;
    suggestions.splice(0, 0, { name: filterText, text: filterText });
    return suggestions;
}
```